Hidden Expression Error when Swapping Datasets
In Microsoft Report Builder, I'm using an existing SSRS report to create a new report; in creating the new report, I've added a new Dataset, and I adjusted the main tablix and all its components to refer to the new Dataset.  However, when I try to save the new report, I get an error saying that "The Hidden expression for the tablix 'Tablix1' refers to the field...." and it mentions a field from the OLD dataset.
But the Hidden expression actually doesn't reference anything.  I verified in both places that I know to check: 1) the Visibility tab in the Tablix Properties pop-up window, 2) the Hidden expression on the Properties menu on the right-hand side of Design view.
Neither of those places referenced any field at all.  The Visibility tab was marked as "Show," and the Hidden expression was completely blank.  I also tried to explicitly change the Hidden expression to =False, but I still get the same error upon trying to save.  I deleted the old dataset, in hopes that that might sever whatever link is behind the scenes, but that also did nothing.
I must be missing some third place where the Hidden expression can get programmed.  I'd appreciate any help.

open the RDL in XML and search for the hidden expression and try removing it from there. Make a copy first before you edit the XML
